# Shape does not fill entirely in Illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6

[image]

As you can see in the picture above. I can't fully fill the hair with color, why is that?

Comment: could you explain a bit more about what you've done and tried? How did you make the hair etc.. Right now, it looks to me you have a shape that crosses its own outline instead of a regular one, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I downvoted your question because we cannot assume what is the issue until we know how you made the hair.

Comment: Illustrator is such garbage. "simply" use live paint bucket. Just let the user make fill shapes. Ugh, I hate this program so much.

Comment: Connect all the dots first. The hair is not one element, they are many different elements that need to be closed in order to add fill color.

Answer (score 3):

**Close your shapes.**

Your example image would seem to reflect what happens when you have a **series of disjointed, unconnected paths** and then apply a fill to them. If you look, each and every one of your 2 or 3 sided shapes is filled using it's end anchors as the basis for the third side of the fill.

You need to **close shapes** entirely if you want them to fill as a single object. In reality, open paths with fills can cause all sorts of issues. Not issues directly within Illustrator, but upon output or when files are migrated to another application.

You can simply select all and use the **Live Paint Bucket Tool** to click and fill areas. The Live Paint Bucket Tool will auto-close shapes when creating fills.